# Asp.net Entity Framework.6.1.3 NuGet package - what are folders net40 and net45

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Can anyone tell me in Asp.net `EntityFramework.6.1.3` NuGet package, what are the folders `net40` and `net45`?

Comment: Those are the binaries for .NET 4.0 (net40) and .NET 4.5 (net45) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folders contain version-specific assemblies of the EF6 library.

When you install a package manually using the Package Manager Console, the software creates two EntityFramework libraries (4.0 and 4.5) and **automatically** adds a reference to the correct library based on the selected project.

If you are not installing this using the command line tool, choose the library  version that matches your target framework.

Comment: Means, If I have TargetFramework 4.5 then I should use .dll in (net45)  OR If I have  TargetFramework 4.0 then i should use .dll in (net40) folder ??

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Choose the version that matches your target framework.